# Python List is printing duplicates and cannot index values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logging

I am reading from a huge log file and looking for particular keywords. When they are found, I need to print each line that has the found keyword. Currently my code prints duplicate lines as many as the lines found from my list. Here is my code below. This is the updated and modified full code of what I did, basically here I found that it sends the lines with the keyword error, with an end line and is a bit slow, is it possible for me to just only print the first line using indexing:

```
important = []
phrases = ['Error']

with open("mypath\\to\\my\\logfile.log") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    for line in file:
        for phrase in phrases:
            if phrase in line:
                important.append(line)
                pattern = 'ERROR*' or 'Warning*'
                matching = fnmatch.filter(important, pattern)
                myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("myTeamsWebhook")
                if len(important) != 0:
                    # Add text to the message.
                    myTeamsMessage.text(str(matching))
                    # send the message.
                    myTeamsMessage.send()
                    # print(matching)
                    break
                else:
                    # Add text to the message.
                    myTeamsMessage.text("Log has no error, proceed with deployment")
                    # send the message.
                    myTeamsMessage.send()
                break
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the contents of the logfile? That would really help understand where the problem might be coming from.

Comment: Perhaps you just need a `break` after the `print()`, because when you print, then one phrase has had a match, so no point in testing more phrases.

Comment: @Jonathon H, unfortunately I can’t share the file it’s got confidential data.

Comment: @quamrana I tried that, and it seems to work, but I have a condition that further assesses if that list is not empty and sends a notification alert to MS Teams, but it’s a bit slow.

Comment: That sounds like you are ready to ask a different question.

Comment: `pattern = 'ERROR*' or 'Warning*'` has *EXACTLY* the same result as `pattern = 'ERROR*'` - it doesn't somehow put two strings in a single variable, it just chooses the first non-empty string (or otherwise truthy value).

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for pointing that out, I think I noticed that it only takes a single parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## updated snippet with import of fnmatch

```
import fnmatch
#important lines?
important = []
phrases = ['Null-Reference-Exception']

with open("logfile.log") as file:
  line = file.readline()
  for line in file:
    for phrase in phrases:
      #print("Line", line)
      #print("phrase", phrase)
      if phrase in line:
        important.append(line)
        pattern = 'ERROR*' or 'Warning*'
        #https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html
        matching = fnmatch.filter(important, pattern)
        print(str(matching))
```

## my example logfile contents:

```
WARNING: You forgot to initialize a variable on line 27
ERROR: This code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception 34
ERROR: This other code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception line 290
```

## output with this example

```
['ERROR: This code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception 34\n']
['ERROR: This code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception 34\n', 'ERROR: This other code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception line 290']
```

Do you mean the second list in output above being the duplicate?
Your current code adds important lines and then filters any that match pattern for the print. Perhaps an if statement might do what you want? Might need more clarification if this is not what you meant.

## Updated snippet (perhaps this is your intent)

```
import fnmatch
#important lines?
important = []
phrases = ['Null-Reference-Exception']
matches = []
with open("logfile.log") as file:
  line = file.readline()
  for line in file:
    for phrase in phrases:
      #print("Line", line)
      #print("phrase", phrase)
      if phrase in line:
        important.append(line)
        pattern = 'ERROR*' or 'Warning*'
        #https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html
        matching = fnmatch.filter(important, pattern)
        for m in matching:
          if m not in matches:
            matches.append(m)
print(str(matches))
```

## I used the same input as above

## New Output

```
['ERROR: This code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception 34\n', 'ERROR: This other code broke unexpectedly Null-Reference-Exception line 290']
```

Comment: If this is not what you meant can you provide some clarity on what you mean by duplicates. Feel free to use my input or output I just faked it trying to understand your problem better

Comment: This looks really good @Jonathon H. :) I will definitely try it. Can you please review my updated question once again, sorry not familiar much with using Stackoverflow in asking questions hence I modified it lol.

Comment: This worked liked a charm @Jonathon H. thanks mate :)

Comment: Of course. Always happy to help another python dev. Also if you are curious a great library is https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html does great where debug logs don't show up in prod. Then you can just write logs from beginning

Comment: Awesome stuff, I think this library would help quite a lot.